# Merge Sort in C compiles, but doesn't sort

Tags: c, recursion, merge, logic, mergesort

I made this program to sort an array. It works fine, but it won't sort! Please help me find the error in my logic. Thanks

[UPDATE] It was able to work! I just brought down the i, j, and k as suggested below.Also, from i

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mergesort(int[], int, int);
void merge(int [], int low, int mid, int hi); //function prototype

int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,4,78,92,9};
    mergesort(arr,0,5);
    //after mergesort
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void mergesort(int aptr[], int low, int hi)
{
    int mid =0;
    int rightmax=0;
    int leftmax=0;

    if(low==hi)
    {
        return;
    }
    mid=(low+hi)/2;
    mergesort(aptr, low, mid);
    mergesort(aptr, mid+1, hi);
    merge(aptr, low, mid, hi);
}

void merge(int aptr[], int low, int mid, int hi)
{
    int j, i, k;

    //copy contents of aptr to auxiliary b 
    for(i=low; i<=hi; i++)
    {
        bptr[i]=aptr[i]; 
    }

    // iterate through b as if they were still two arrays, lower and higher
    //copy smaller elements first
    i=low;
    j=mid+1;
    k=low;

    while(i<= mid && j<=hi)
    {
        if(bptr[i]<=bptr[j])//<--put smaller element first
        {
            aptr[k++]=bptr[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            aptr[k++]=bptr[j++];
        }
    } 
    // copy back first half just in case
    while(i<=mid)
    {
        aptr[k++]=bptr[i++];
    }
   }//function
```

Comment: How can the program work fine if it doesn’t sort? ;-)

Comment: @Billy: I agree with your brace style. Thanks for the edit. :-)

Comment: @Cody: Go [Allman style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style_.28bsd_in_Emacs.29)! :) Seriously though I won't usually mess with style unless the posted code has a *lack* of any consistent style. You're very welcome for the edit though.

Answer (score 2):

The statement `i<= mid && j<=hi` is never true when your program executes, hence, the while loop that depends on it is never entered and your code that actually swaps elements is never reached.

After the `for` loop that precedes it, `i` is equal to `hi`, which is always greater than `mid`.  I am guessing you mean to reset `i` to be equal to `low` before you enter that `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion for how to start: put printf() calls into your mergesort() and merge() functions that display the parameters at the start and return of each function call. That might help you figure out what's going on. Asking other people to debug your algorithm isn't going to to help you learn how to program.

Comment: Better yet: use a real debugger that lets you watch variables and function calls stepwise.  Using `printf` for debugging is a rather clumsy way of going about things.

Comment: It's perfectly fine (and often constructive) to ask for help when debugging. Sometimes, if you look at a function long enough, you become blind to obvious problems. A second, or third set of eyeballs in that case is truly helpful :) I do agree that using an actual debugger would have been the next logical step, I'm just sayin ...

Answer (score 0):

As a sundry point I'd like to mention that you've fallen victim to error of possible integer overflow:

```
mid=(low+hi)/2;
```

If `low` and/or `hi` are big enough, `low + hi` will overflow, giving you the wrong value for `mid`. Instead you should do this:

```
mid = low + (hi - low) / 2;
```

Comment: If you used `size_t` for these variables, then on any real-world implementation where `ptrdiff_t` has the same size as `size_t` (and thus one fewer value bits), the overflow is not possible.